# Python requests with proxy failing for WinError 10060

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I'm trying to initiate some requests with Python using a proxy but I'm not having success doing so. I have no idea what I am doing wrong and the error doesn't make enough sense to me. Below is the code I am using:

```
proxy_url = 'us6277.nordvpn.com'
auth = (username, password)
proxies = {
    'http': proxy_url,
    'https': proxy_url,
}
requests.get('https://google.com', proxies=proxies, auth=auth)
```

The error I am getting is

> requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000014C006414C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond')))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt to connect to google.com on port 443 failed with max retries exceeded:
`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url`

This was caused by:
`ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy. NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000014C006414C0>: Failed to establish a new connection:`

Specifically caused by:
`[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond` (your proxy failed to respond)

The issue is that your attempt to connect to the proxy is invalid. You are passing `auth=auth` to the call to `requests.get()` which is the incorrect place to put proxy auth credentials. [Here's the documentation on proxies for requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies). You'll need to provide your credentials in `'http': 'http://username:password@us6277.nordvpn.com/'` format.